# Get github API results more than 100

Tags: api, github, search, github-api, rate-limiting

I want to develop github alike issue tracker.
For that i have been working on this below api.
*https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/issues?per_page=100*
But this api results only 100 results per request as per docs.
Is there a way i can get all results of issues and not just 100,i can make multiple request but i don't think it is feasible way of doing it.
Issue object itself contain author,label,assignee so needed all results at once.
*Is there any way to do it?*

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to get all of the results without pagination.  GitHub, like almost all major web sites, has a time limit on the amount of time a request can take.  If you have a repository with, say, 150 000 issues, then any reasonable operation on all of those issues will take longer than the timeout.  Therefore, it doesn't make sense for GitHub to allow you to disable pagination in this way because the request would invariably fail anyway.

Even if you use the GraphQL API, you still get a limited number of results.  If you want to fetch all of the issues, you'll need to make multiple requests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,ok i understand i can use pagination.
https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/issues?per_page=10&page=1 ,so with this i will be able to show 10 issues per page, but what about the filter data like author,assignee,label there i will be requiring all the data at once inorder to filter from all data,since all those filters data i am getting from issue object itself , i won't be able to get all data at once and only max 100,so i don't think it is going to help to just show filter data as per 10 results,this is where i am stuck, can you help how can i proceed with that.

Comment: I feel there is no other api where i can get author,assignee and label data w.r.t to any particular repo issues, apart from getting it from issues object itself(max 100 resutls),so i don't know how to proceed with that